# Can't access nested values with map_dbl r

Tags: r, nested

I can't access the values with map_dbl() as normal. During a lecture this worked perfectly for the teacher.

```
url <- paste0("http://api.kolada.se/v2/data/kpi/", "U09401", "/year/", 2017)
data <- fromJSON(getURL(url))
value <- map_dbl(data$values$values, c(4,1))
map_dbl(data$values$values, c(4,1))
value
```

numeric(0)

This works as expected but how do i get all the values without specifying the index?

```
map_dbl(data$values[[9]]$values, c(4,1))
```

[1] 64 60 62

Comment: I am confused by your question? I ran your code and i get output 2941 numbers? do you have all the libraries loaded?

Comment: I think so, these are the loaded libraries. tidyverse, dplyr, httr, jsonlite, lubridate, rkolada, knitr, listviewer, pageviews, rlist, xml2, rvest, RCurl, purrr. I think it has something to do with the fact that i use mac since it works for everyone else.